# Rails select records using an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in my `ProfilesController#Index`:

```
      @profiles = []
      profile_ids = current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).pluck(:profile_id)
      profile_ids.each do |id|
        @profiles << Profile.find(id)
      end
```

I tried doing this:

```
@profiles = current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).pluck(:profile_id).each do |id|
    Profile.find(id)
end
```

But for some reason, that would only put the value of `:profile_id` into `@profiles` and not the actual `Profile(find(id))` like I want.

There a way to do this more elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
profile_ids = current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).pluck(:profile_id)
@profiles = Profile.where(:id => profile_ids)
```

The second line will search in `Profile` model with the given array `profile_ids`
It will generate a SQL like `SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id IN (1,2,3..)`

**Edit**: Another form: `@profiles = Profile.find(profile_ids)`

Comment: Ahh right. Ofcourse. Yeh....that's what I was trying to remember....how do I search for all the profiles given a collection of `ids`. I can even contract it further into one line by putting the entire first line in the second.

Comment: Nah I know how to do it. I was just speaking out loud. Thanks for the response. I got it from here.

Comment: Ah alright, I couldn't clearly catch you speaking out loud :))

Comment: My bad. One more thing....why does it not retrieve the Profiles in the order they were in the `profile_ids` array? They seem to be returning randomly, or in some other order than the `profile_ids` order.

Comment: I don't see why is that happening, how many ids are there in `profile_ids` on an average? I tried running a test in rails console 8 and 7 IDS multiple times and it was always the correct order.

Comment: Yes, `Profile.find(profile_ids)` works. I just stumbled upon that. You can add that answer to the other question and I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: No, `Profile.find(array)` doesn't really work. That query doesn't have an ORDER BY so the results aren't guaranteed to come out in any particular order. `Profile.where(...)` has the same problem because it doesn't have an ORDER BY either.

Comment: @muistooshort care to show an example in code of what will work, all the time?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with selecting the Profile IDs first, and then doing something like `Profile.where(id: profile_ids).to_a` is that you won't get the results in the expected order.

On the other hand, the main issue with your query is that you will be performing N+1 queries, N being the size of `profile_ids`. The following query should perform only two, and give you the profiles in the expected order:

```
profiles = current_user.ratings.order(speed: :desc).includes(:profile).map(&:profile)
```

More info about N+1 queries [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Comment: Will a statement like this `@profiles = Profile.find(profile_ids)` result in N queries as well? I agree with that N+1 problem is true for the block code by OP.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Both are exactly the same. You provide a list of IDs to filter by, and the query it produces is something like `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, without any order.

Comment: That wasn't exactly what I was asking. Do you mean that the statement `@profiles = Profile.find(profile_ids)` will generate `SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` statement which will query the database 5 times?

Comment: Oh, no no! It generates a single query, same as `Profile.where(profile_ids)`

Comment: N+1 exists if you make a query, and for every returned item you make an additional query. As I already said, `Profile.find(profile_ids)` generates 1 query instead of `N` (where `N = profile_ids.size`)